# vim fails to load dynamic library

Tags: vim, homebrew

I just upgraded brew: `brew update` and `brew upgrade` and it broke `vim`. Running `vim` gives this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.26.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib  
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.0050/bin/vim
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Now, `.../perl5/5.26.2` has been overwritten by `.../perl5/5.28.0`. How do I update `vim` dependencies?

Comment: No idea what they did, but I cannot get older versions of `vim` to work, I've lost `python3` support and `jedi-vim` no longer works. What in the world did `brew`/`vim` do?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been struggling with this for a few days. Dunno who did what terrible, but:

You can `switch` (and furthermore `pin`) versions of `brew` packages:

```
$ brew info perl  # lists all the perl version installed
$ brew switch perl 5.26.2
$ brew pin perl  # don't let `brew update` change this
```

Then, I got an error about `python` being broken/unavailable...

```
$ brew info python
$ brew switch python 3.6.5  # 3.7.0 appears to break things
$ brew pin python
```

Now, `vim` may work at whatever version it's at (eg `8.1.0150`), but if it doesn't, you can try different versions until one works I guess...:

```
$ brew info vim
$ brew switch vim 8.1.0001
$ brew pin vim
```

Comment: Just checked. `vim/8.1.0150` works with `perl/5.26.2` and `python/3.6.5_1`. `vim/8.1.0050` has issues.

Comment: Oh, hmm - when I `brew install vim --update` it tries to install `8.1.0150`, and as a dependency tries to install `python 3.7.0`. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure *which* combination was the problematic one; I just know the above works for me. I only just figured out how to pin, so maybe pinning `perl` and `python` would've been sufficient? Glad it's working though! **updated** to have clearer wording

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, but was able to keep the up-to-date homebrew releases and maintain `vim` functionality.

First, `homebrew` upgrades Python from 3.6 to 3.7 as part of the `vim` upgrade (not sure what toggle is needed to prevent that). When that happens, you'll "lose" all of your `pip` modules (they aren't lost, they just aren't ported to the new install path, best to `pip3 freeze > pip3.txt` prior so you can easily restore your working module set).

Next, to get `vim` to launch properly, I needed to run a reinstall of perl in homebrew. This re-ran the `make` and `make install` steps, which I am guessing provided the library links vim was looking for.

I had originally got a different machine working with the `brew switch ...` method for moving back to Perl 5.26.2, but that wasn't working on this host. The reinstall did work, however. Now the up-to-date `vim` launches properly alongside the up-to-date `python` and `perl`.